# Passing data from a view model to a view controller using tableView cell in rxSwift

Tags: swift, uikit, rx-swift

So i made a simple reactive tableview to learn rxSwift, I got difficulty on accessing the data in my ViewModel. so I created I think a very bad approach on how to get the data from my viewmodel

```
        tableView.rx.itemSelected
            .subscribe(onNext:{ [weak self] indexPath in
                print("Tapped \(String(describing: self?.hospitalListVM?.result.value[0].id))")
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I don't think that 's rx way on handling data. are there any better solution for my problem about accessing data in my viewModel?

my ViewModel

```
class HospitalListViewModel:APIRequest {
    var baseURL:String = "https://"
    var method: RequestType = .GET
    var result = BehaviorRelay<[RumahSakitModel]>(value: [])
    var isLoaded = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)
    
    func fetchData() {
        guard let url = URL(string:baseURL) else { return }
        let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _,_ in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let hasil = try JSONDecoder().decode([RumahSakitModel].self, from: data)
                self.result.accept(hasil)
                self.isLoaded.accept(true)
            } catch let err {
                print(err)
            }
        }
        session.resume()
    }  
}
```

How I bind my tablewView

```
        hospitalListVM?
            .result
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: HospitalTableCell.identifier, cellType: HospitalTableCell.self)) { _, post, cell in
            cell.configureSubView(title: post.nama ?? " ", subTitle: post.jenis ?? " ")}
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Have you registered the cell and set the delegate of the tableview to `self`?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the output?

Comment: the output it self is the data, like 1 up to n, but I don't think that's approrpriate

Comment: i didnt register it to the tableview delegate, somehow it conflicted with the rxCocoa library

Comment: @VisalRajapakse , well i can get the output, and the output is the id of the data. what I want to know is are there any other appropriate approach on this problem. The rx swift way

Comment: UITableView has a reactive `modelSelected` operator...

Answer (score 0):

The two standard ways of finding the selected object are here:

```
let rumahSakitModel1 = tableView.rx.itemSelected
    .withLatestFrom(hospitalListVM!.result) { $1[$0.row] }

let rumahSakitModel2 = tableView.rx.modelSelected(RumahSakitModel.self)
```

With either of the above, you can then do:

```
rumahSakitModelX
    .subscribe(onNext: { model in
        print("Tapped \(model.id)")
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```